# Migration magento 1 to magento 2 error

Tags: magento2.3, magento-1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I use the tool of Magento for migration data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. After run command lines:

```
php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml -r

php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml

php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

Then I try login load Admin page and it show a bug: Expecting a string, got NULL
[image]

I migarion data from **Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.3.3**.

Log file:

> {"0":"Expecting a string, got NULL","1":"#1
>   Zend\Uri\Uri->parse(NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:140]\n#2
>   Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getHostWithPort(NULL)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:129]\n#3
>   Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend() called
>   at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:106]\n#4
>   Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(true)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/AreaList.php:73]\n#5
>   Magento\Framework\App\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName('admin') called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:132]\n#6
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#7
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000105de3ff000000006232b19b#)
>   called at
>   [index.php:41]\n</pre>","url":"/admin/admin/index/index/key/e6618748e3cbb6430e0c0b54585a0d1938b8fb4c3636584e5f82a21286ef06a1/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you checked log file ? may be there a brief error

Comment: Thank you! I can't find anything log file.

Comment: as per your screen shot,  there should be an error log for above error i.e `Error log record number: 1127444864753`.

Comment: I have updated it, Thank you!

Comment: please add `echo $uriString; die('here');` at `/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php` in `public static function parseScheme($uriString)` function and check what it is printing.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it by run command upgrade and deploy.

Comment: Glad to know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed it by run command line:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Hope it will help someone!

Comment: it helped me! Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: It was very successful!